# Update dataframe if certain condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Any help would be greatly appreciated here:

Lets say I have a Pandas DataFrame such as:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4  Column5 Column6

0  aaa      abb  jnhs  01/01/2020      40   TEST
1  aba      vvv  jnjh  01/01/2020      34   TEST
```

I am looking for the best way to be able to test if a certain condition exists, if it does to take
the number on the same row under the heading "column5" below and add 1 to that number. Then to return the full dataframe with just 1 added to the cells in col5 where col6 ="TEST".

The below is the Dataframe result I am looking for:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4  Column5 Column6

0  aaa      abb  jnhs  01/01/2020      41   TEST
1  aba      vvv  jnjh  01/01/2020      35   TEST
```

What I have tried so far:

`df['Column5'] = np.where(df['Colum6'] == "TEST", +1, "NA")`

This howevever replaces the value in column5 with 1 and does not add 1 to the current value to make them 41 and 35 respectively.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) recommends using a mask to index the desired rows. And then use the `+=` operator as suggested in another answer or index any other row and just add `+1` or any other desired value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"Index" : [0,1, 2], "A": [1, 1, 1],
        "B": [42, 42, 42], "C": ["test","test", "NA"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
>>>df

Index   A   B   C
0   0   1   42  test
1   1   1   42  test
2   2   1   42  NA
```

```
mask = df["C"]=="test"

df.loc[mask, "B"] = df["B"]+1
```

```
>>> df

Index   A   B   C
0   0   1   43  test
1   1   1   43  test
2   2   1   42  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look for the rows where the condition is met, then add +1 to `Column5`

```
mask = df["Column6"] == "TEST"
df.loc[mask, "Column5"] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This work:

```
df['Column5'] = np.where(df['Colum6'] == "TEST", df['Column5']+1, "NA")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
m = df["Column6"].eq("TEST")
df.loc[m, "Column5"] = df.loc[m, "Column5"].add(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
result=df["column6"]=="TEST"
df.loc[result,"column5"]=df["column5"]+1
```